# How can I show an animated action which happens only with triggered precondition?

Tags: animation

I am new to Blender and its been almost 3 months, using it. I have a big presentation coming up and I want to show my Manager my animated CAD Design.

So Basically I Want to show a Door Open (Sliding), **only when we push a button**. Is it possible to do this in Blender? (Just like a Train DOOR)

I know the normal animation method of sliding the DOOR, but I am looking for something where an action needs to happen for the next action to take place.

Can somebody please give me a reference or a video where I can see how it can be done?